Considering 2 Timothy 4:10, was Demas truly born again?
Was Demas, Paul's co-worker, truly born again? And if so, did he lose his faith afterwards? Or was he never truly saved?
Col 4:14  Luke, the beloved physician, and Demas, greet you.
2Tm 4:10  For Demas hath forsaken me, having loved this present world, and is departed unto Thessalonica; Crescens to Galatia, Titus unto Dalmatia.
Fm 24  Marcus, Aristarchus, Demas, Lucas, my fellowlabourers.
Is it possible that Paul did not see whether he had the true fruit of salvation or not?

Please note that the Biblical Hermeneutics Forum, one focuses on the interpretation of specific scriptures. This means you would include quotes from Colossians 4:14, 2 Timothy 4:10, and Philemon 1:24 to begin with. Then include the scriptures on salvation, and finally examine 1 John 2:15. Do you see what I mean? :-)

Absolutely, I haven't asked any questions in a long time and I forgot some rules! Thank you

"Was Demas, Paul's co-worker, truly born again?" — That is a question of interpretation, not of hermeneutics. There is nothing in the quoted scriptures that would of itself lead one to that conclusion. ¶ Also, the expression "born again" is a doctrinal concept, so it shouldn't be used on this site as if it had a well-defined meaning.

Answer
Demas was really a true believer whom Paul called “my fellow-worker” (Phm 1:24).
Explanation
We can have the guarantee for the authenticity of the above fact during the time of the original apostles. They had this meticulous method of confirming and making sure that the gospel is preached properly and genuine believers are joining the church.
Case 1:-

“And the apostles in Jerusalem hearing that Samaria had received the
Word of God, they sent Peter and John to them, who going down
prayed concerning them so that they may receive the Holy Spirit. For
He had not yet fallen on any one of them, but they were only being
baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus. Then they laid hands on them,
and they received the Holy Spirit” (Acts 8:14-17).

Case 2:-

“And the Word was heard in the ears of the church in Jerusalem. And
they sent out Barnabas, that he should go as far as Antioch; who was glad when he had come and had seen the grace of God. And he
exhorted all with purpose of heart to remain near to the Lord” (Acts
11:22-23).

Case 3:-

“And it happened, in the time Apollos was in Corinth, Paul was passing
through the higher parts to come to Ephesus. And finding some
disciples, he said to them, Believing, did you receive the Holy
Spirit? And they said to him, We did not even hear whether the Holy
Spirit is. And he said to them, Then to what were you baptized? And
they said, To the baptism of John. And Paul said, John indeed baptized
with a baptism of repentance, saying to the people that they should
believe into the One coming after him, that is, into the Christ,
Jesus. And hearing, they were baptized into the name of the Lord
Jesus. And Paul laying hands on them, the Holy Spirit came on
them, and they spoke in languages and prophesied” (Acts 19:1-6).

So, we can see that the original apostles always made sure that the Gospel was preached in the proper way throughout the places.
Besides, Lord Jesus Christ was guiding them in those days when the Church was in the fledgling state.

“And the Lord said to him (Ananias), Go, for this one is a chosen
vessel to Me, to bear My name before nations and kings and the sons of
Israel. For I will show him how much he must suffer for the sake
of My name” (Acts 9:15-16).


“And the Lord said to Paul through a vision in the night, Do not fear,
but speak, and do not keep silence; because I am with you, and no
one shall set on you to oppress you; because there is much people to
Me in this city” (Acts 18:9-10).

Because of all of the above facts, we can be assured that Demas was a true believer. He was “saved through the washing of regeneration and renewal of the Holy Spirit” (Titus 3:5).
Did he lose his faith afterwards?
Definitely, because Paul says clearly:

“For Demas deserted me, loving the present age” (2 Tim 4:10).

What is the problem with that?

“Do not love the world nor the things in the world. If anyone loves
the world, the love of the Father is not in him” (1 John 2:15).

Also,

“And be not conformed to this age” (Rom 12:2).

But, unfortunately, Demas did just that, as confirmed by Paul.
Is he lost for ever?
We cannot say. It could be a temporary relapse.
Shall we judge him?
Not at all.

“Who are you judging another's servant? To his own master he stands or
falls. But he will stand, for God is able to make him stand” (Rom
14:4).


“Then do not judge anything before the time, until the Lord comes, who
will both shed light on the hidden things of darkness and will reveal
the counsels of the hearts. And then praise will be to each one from
God” (1 Cor 4:5).

Conclusion
So, Demas was a true believer with true fruit of salvation as otherwise Paul would not call him “my fellow-worker”. But, last time we hear of him, he deviated from the Way. And we are clueless about what happened afterwards. But God knows.


“For Demas hath forsaken me, having loved this present world, and is
departed unto Thessalonica; Crescens to Galatia, Titus unto Dalmatia.” (2Ti >4:10)

It is unfair to equate "...Demas hath forsaken me, having loved this present world,.." with the story of Peter when he denied Jesus three times.
A few hours earlier during the last supper, Peter was 'swearing' his allegiance to Jesus.

“But Peter said unto him, Although all shall be offended, yet will not I.”
(Mrk 14:29)

He did it with sincerity. This does not look like someone who 'loved this present world' (whatever that means).
After the denial, what was Peter's reaction?

“And the second time the cock crew. And Peter called to mind the word that >Jesus said unto him, Before the cock crow twice, thou shalt deny me thrice. >And when he thought thereon, he wept.” (Mrk 14:72)

Mark says "...he wept." Mark was commonly believed to be Peter's amanuensis in writing the Gospel according to Mark. Hence, Peter reported his own story through Mark.

“And Peter remembered the word of Jesus, which said unto him, Before the cock >crow, thou shalt deny me thrice. And he went out, and wept bitterly.” (Mat >26:75)

Again, this does not look like Peter 'loved this present world' because Matthew says that Peter 'wept bitterly'.

“And the Lord turned, and looked upon Peter. And Peter remembered the word of >the Lord, how he had said unto him, Before the cock crow, thou shalt deny me >thrice. And Peter went out, and wept bitterly.” (Luk 22:61-62).

"Peter went out, and wept bitterly"......It is unfair to align Peter's denial of Jesus with Demas's forsaking of Paul.
Let us look at the text in 2Tim.4:10 once again carefully.

“For Demas hath forsaken me, having loved this present world, and is departed >unto Thessalonica; Crescens to Galatia, Titus unto Dalmatia.” (2Ti 4:10)

It starts with the simple fact that "....Demas has forsaken ME,.." (capital mine).
Paul said that Demas forsook HIM (Paul). Why waste ink in writing that he(Paul) was the one forsaken by Demas? Why didn't Paul tell us that "Demas has forsaken Jesus Christ"? Why beat about the bush?
"...Demas has forsaken me" means that Demas left Paul.
Let us look at the next statement in the verse: "...having left this present world...".
Again, why can't Paul tell us straightway by saying something like "....having left Christ..." or "...having left the faith...." if truly he believed that Demas left the faith or forsook his faith in Christ Jesus? I think people are reading into the text.
It seems, to me that interpreting from the text that 'Demas left the faith' or 'abandoned the faith' or 'left Christ' is an argument from silence.
John Mark who was 'sister's son to Barnabas' (Col.4:10) forsook Paul and Barnabas at a point.

“But Paul thought not good to take him with them, who departed from them from >Pamphylia, and went not with them to the work.” (Act 15:38)

Is it fair to say that Mark, in forsaking Paul and Barnabas left the faith? I think not.
The scripture says that Mark "...departed from them from Pamphilia,..". It is similar in echo to what Paul wrote about Demas when he wrote that Demas "....has forsaken me...". Nowhere in the scripture are we told that Mark forsook the faith or that Mark abandoned his faith in Christ. Mark only left Paul and Barnabas, and it seems similar in echo that Demas left Paul and would not continue with Paul '...to the work.'
At best we can safely say that Demas left PAUL but no indication that he left the faith.
As we can see from Mark's case, leaving Paul is not synonymous with abandoning the faith.
I also do not have any reason to doubt Demas's faith in Christ Jesus. There is no information to suggest such. 2Tim. 4:10 alone is not enough text to determine that Demas left the faith. All we know is that Demas left Paul; Paul says that Demas left him (Paul).
Paul is not known to be such that would waste words or dance around the bush; he is not known to want to confuse his readers. His 'yes' is yes and his 'nay' nay.

Welcome to BH. +1 for layout. However if the writer only knew that Demas loved the world and did not know if he would eventually repent of this then personally I think we have to keep an open mind. Some seeds are choked by the deceitfulness of riches and do not bear fruit. [Matthew 13:22-23]

The order in which these letters were written makes a difference. According to Bible Gateway, Colossians, and Philemon were likely written c. 61-63 CE while 2 Timothy was written c. 66-67 CE.
https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/intro/?search=Romans&version=NCB
Colossians 4:14 includes greetings from Luke and Demas. In Paul’s letter to Philemon 1:24, Paul includes Demas in the list of “my fellow workers.” However, 2 Timothy 4:10 ESV reads

For Demas, in love with this present world, has deserted me and gone
to Thessalonica. Crescens has gone to Galatia, Titus to Dalmatia.

In John 15:19 ESV, we read that Jesus said

If you were of the world, the world would love you as its own; but
because you are not of the world, but I chose you out of the world,
therefore the world hates you.

In 1 John 2:15-17 ESV, we read

Do not love the world or the things in the world. If anyone loves the
world, the love of the Father is not in him. For all that is in the
world—the desires of the flesh and the desires of the eyes and pride
of life—is not from the Father but is from the world. And the world is
passing away along with its desires, but whoever does the will of God
abides forever.

We’re also reminded of Jesus’ parable of the sower in Matthew 13. In verses 20-22 ESV, Jesus explains

As for what was sown on rocky ground, this is the one who hears the
word and immediately receives it with joy, yet he has no root in
himself, but endures for a while, and when tribulation or persecution
arises on account of the word, immediately he falls away. As for what
was sown among thorns, this is the one who hears the word, but the
cares of the world and the deceitfulness of riches choke the word, and
it proves unfruitful.

So, it seems that Demas, “being in love with the present world,” deserted Paul and ceased being fruitful.
Mark also once had deserted Paul, but was reconciled later. We have no account of what happened to Demas, however. Of course, Peter and the other disciples also deserted Jesus, but were reconciled.
Jesus said that “the one who endures to the end will be saved” in Matthew 10:22, Matthew 24:13, and Mark 13:13. Whether Demas was truly saved or not might well be a question that can only be answered by God after Demas’ life came to an end.
Note: The early church was faced with the dilemma of Christians recanting their faith under torture or threat of execution. Should they be allowed to rejoin the fellowship of believers? If I remember correctly, the early church decided to allow one failure. Also note that both Peter and Judas repented of their denial and betrayal.

2 Timothy 4:10

for Demas, because he loved this world, has deserted me and has gone to Thessalonica.

The Greek word for "loved", "agapaó" (Strong's 25), represent a love that is unchanging and unconditional, the same kind of love that God has for us.
When Paul used this word to describe Demas, he implied that Demas's love for the world remained unchanged, despite his contributions to the ministry.
From this perspective, I believe that Demas was never truly saved.

The question then is this: how could Paul not realize that he was not saved? That is, I don't think he didn't recognize the fruits of those around him.

@Leandro - Paul should know that it is not his knowledge to determine who will be saved. His commend about Demas is merely a factual statement, indicating that Demas had not changed since Paul knew him. Without further documentation about Demas, I would consider Demas had not been saved up to this point.

I believe that Paulo knows who is saved or not by seeing the fruits. He said it to the Galatians, the Thessalonians etc...So I think Demas was saved, but he apostatized from the faith

God alone knows this answer, but I believe Demas is secure.  For clarification, I would like to reiterate what was required via Paul's gospel for salvation then and for today, and what happens at the moment of belief in it that might shed some light on the question.
The sole requirement for salvation then and now is to hear (or come to the knowledge of) the gospel (1 Cor 15:1-4) and believe it, which is to then have faith alone in Jesus Christ alone:
Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,

Ephesians 2:8-9

For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God:
9 Not of works, lest any man should boast.

When someone has placed their faith in Jesus Christ they are at that moment "sealed unto the day of redemption" by the Spirit:
Ephesians 4:30

And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.

I see Demas as being one who believed, but who may have later "fallen from grace", meaning he was led back to belief in a works-based plan for salvation.  He "fell" (forgot) what God's grace means.  Although still eternally secure due to his original belief, Demas may lose an eternal reward at the Judgement Seat of Christ.
1 Corinthians 3:13-15

Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire shall try every man's work of what sort it is.
14 If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward.
15 If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.

Following "another gospel" (Gal 1:6-10) is what Paul warns of, and Demas may have very well done just that.
Galatians 5:4-8

Christ is become of no effect unto you, whosoever of you are justified by the law; ye are fallen from grace.
5 For we through the Spirit wait for the hope of righteousness by faith.
6 For in Jesus Christ neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision; but faith which worketh by love.
7 Ye did run well; who did hinder you that ye should not obey the truth?
8 This persuasion cometh not of him that calleth you.


This is odd! - How can one "fall from grace" and still be saved if grace is the only means of salvation?

@Dottard Because "falling from grace" never implies "losing salvation".  Yes, it is by God's grace (not works) that one is saved upon having faith.  Forgetting that it is by God's grace (after salvation) does not mean that one is losing their salvation.  2 Timothy 2:13 "If we believe not, yet he abideth faithful: he cannot deny himself."

Really strange!  I know of people who were once believers and baptized who became murderers, drug dealers, blasphemers and adulterers - all at once - are such people who repudiated God, still saved?  Does God really over-ride their choice?

@Dottard Water baptism?  That means nothing today.

perhaps - but what of his declaration of faith in Jesus?

@Dottard Only God knows if it was sincere.  Anyone can proclaim it, but do they truly believe it?
